# Create Autoencoder Model Using Keras Subclassing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'd want to create an autoencoder subclassing the Keras Model class, I don't know if there is away of creating both encoder and decoder separately and combine them into a new `AutoEncoder` class or I need to create both encoder and decoder in the same class.

This is an example of a super simple autoencoder in one class:

```
INPUT_SHAPE = 254
class AutoEncoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Encoder
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,), activation='relu')
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(INPUT_SHAPE, activation='relu')

        #Decoder
        self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
    
    def __call__(self, inp, training=False):  
        x = self.dense1(inp)
        x = self.dense2(x)   

        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.dense4(x)
        return x
```

And this would be `encoder` and `decoder` is separated classes, my doubt is how can I combine both? or what would be the best way of creating an autoencoder in this case.

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,), activation='relu')
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(INPUT_SHAPE, activation='relu')
    
    def __call__(self, inp, training=False):        
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        return x
    
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,), activation='relu')
        self.dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
        
    def __call__(self, inp, training=False):
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.dense4(x)
        return x
```

Comment: I don't think it matters, the output of encoder should be passed to decoder and you should be able to calculate loss to train it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 minor mistakes in the code you provided. Like `INPUT_SHAPE` not provided in `__init__`. Also, use `call` method instead of `__call__`

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, INPUT_SHAPE):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,), activation='relu')
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(INPUT_SHAPE, activation='relu')
    
    def call(self, inp, training=False):        
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        return x
    
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, INPUT_SHAPE):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,), activation='relu')
        self.dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
        
    def call(self, inp, training=False):
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.dense4(x)
        return x
```

Once these are fixed. You can define AE using following

```
class AE(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, INPUT_SHAPE):
    super(AE, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = Encoder(INPUT_SHAPE)
    self.decoder = Decoder(INPUT_SHAPE)

  def call(self, inp):
    out_encoder = self.encoder(inp)
    out_decoder = self.decoder(out_encoder)
    return out_encoder, out_decoder
```

Its time for some action. Lets instantiate this class and check the object.

```
INPUT_SHAPE = 10 
model = AE(10) 
model
>>>
<__main__.AE at 0x7f5bb4ef8dd8>
```

You can also check encoder and decoder

```
model.encoder
model.decoder
```

This will give `<__main__.Encoder at 0x7f5bb4ed2710>` and `<__main__.Decoder at 0x7f5bb4ec99e8>`